# How index.d.ts of @type/node was loaded

Tags: node.js, typescript

to make my first nodejs program with typescript. maybe i need import or references index.d.ts of @types/node. but it work just after exectue
`npm install @types/node` and append code like this `import { setTimeout } from 'timers'`

but way it was referenced.

sorry for my poor english and thanks.

Comment: Could you please we more specific? Where the code was inserted(appended)? in your `file_name.ts` file  remember that you need to compule your code using `tsc file_name.ts`

Comment: @Teocci I believe he meant: "why don't I have to reference the `@types` file I just installed, why is it automatically picked up when I add the `import` clause?"

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript has an approximation of NodeJS's module resolution algorithm baked into it so that it can make this scenarios easier.

When you do not specify a value for `--module`, or `"module"` in `tsconfig.json`, it defaults to `"commonjs"` which in turn defaults the `--moduleResolution` setting to "node".

In addition to recursively traversing the `node_modules` directories above and within your working directory looking for files and directories matching the imported name, this also enables automatic resolution of the `"packageName"` >>> `packageName/package.json.main` resolution behavior of the NodeJS require function. It also enables the `"packageName"` >>> `packageName/index` convention where NodeJS *requires* a directory as a module via its index file.

In your case, this is how, roughly speaking, it resolves `index.d.ts` automatically:

When you import from a *non-relative* module specifier, it looks in `node_modules` directory adjacent to the working directory.

From there it first looks for an `@types` subdirectory.

If it finds a directory with the same name as the import, it looks for a `package.json` file in that directory.

If it finds a `package.json` with a `"main"` property it resolves the import to that file.

That file is `index.d.ts`.

Hint: to see this in action pass the `--traceResolution` flag to `tsc`, or set

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "traceResolution": true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

in `tsconfig.json`.

Look at the output and you will see its file system walking behavior and each attempt to resolve the import.

Comment: I think i missing the document about "@types, typeRoots and types"..the "traceResolution" option really help me. thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html is great as you hint at. There is a lot of info there, so you may will likely refer to it many times.